# Complex path integral $\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{5z^²-8}{z^3-2z^2}dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to practice by computing

$$\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{5z^²-8}{z^3-2z^2}dz$$

I've first tried to expand in partial fractions and then set $z=e^{i\theta}$, but while it first simplifies quite nicely, it then ends up presenting some integrals that aren't really nice (I get one that's not converging).

I'm wondering whether maybe there is a simpler way, or if I've just made a mistake in my computation and could see a right one... Is the integrand actually differentiable on all open regions of $\mathbb{C}$ not containing $0$ and $2$? I can't prove it but I feel it's true, then I could apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for path integrals...

Can you help me clarify all this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Partial fractions and Cauchy's integral formula works well.

Comment: How can I manage $\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{dz}{z-2} dz$ with Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: In its most general version, Cauchy's integral formula says that $\displaystyle f^{(k)}(z_0)I_\gamma(z_0)=\dfrac {k!}{2\pi i}\int _\gamma \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}\mathrm dz$, where $I_\gamma(z_0)$ denotes the winding number of $z_0$ with respect to $\gamma$. If you don't know this, at this point you probably know that the integral you mention in the comment is $0$ because the singularity lies outside the circle.

Comment: Right, it's $0$ because $\frac{1}{z-2}$ is holomorphic on the closed disc bounded by $\gamma(0,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's enough.

Comment: In order to use Cauchy formula you need the function to be holomorphic in an *open* set containing the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use partial fractions:
$$
\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{5z^²-8}{z^3-2z^2}dz = 5\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{1}{z-2}dz - 8\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{1}{z^2(z-2)}dz
$$
The first integral is zero since the function $\frac{1}{z-2}$ is holomorphic in a convex neighbourhood of the curve. For the second integral we use Cauchy's Theorem and again the fact that $\frac{1}{z-2}$ is holomorphic:
$$
\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{1}{z^2(z-2)}dz = \int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{\frac{1}{z-2}}{z^2}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{1!}f^{(1)}(0) = 2\pi i\frac{-1}{(z-2)^2}\left.\right|_{z=0} = -\frac{\pi i}{2}
$$
Which yields $I = 4\pi i$.